# dateTime range query

Tags: javascript, marklogic

In my ML8 database there are some JSON documents containing Dtm fields. An example you can see below at 'Data:'.
I have an element range index of scalar type dateTime on this field and to check if that works I use the query you see below at 'Test:'. The results are as expected.

Now when I try to query this, I want to grab all documents with a Dtm field past a certain date, this query returns nothing. You can see the query below at 'Query:'.

Data:

```
"Dtm": "2015-06-25T07:11:10.0Z"
```

Query:

```
var date = xs.dateTime("2015-06-01T14:38:09.145231+02:00");
var b    = cts.elementRangeQuery("Dtm", ">", date);
var c    = cts.search(b);
c
```

Test:

```
cts.elementValues([xs.QName("Dtm")], null, ['limit=3'], null, 1.0, null);
```

TestResult:

```
2015-06-11T17:43:36
2015-06-11T17:43:37
2015-06-11T17:43:38
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a `cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery`, and use `fn.subsequence` to grab just one page of results instead of all. For example like this:

```
var date = "2015-06-16T07:11:10.0Z";
var b    = cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("Dtm", ">", date);
var c    = fn.subsequence(cts.search(b, ['unfiltered']), 1, 10);
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks. Trying to do this: 
cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("Dtm", ">", xs.dateTime(date), ["max-occurs=1"]);
Keeps hitting tree cache full or crashes my browser window.

Comment: The max-occurs option on the range query will not limit the total number of search results. Use fn.subsequence for that purpose..

Comment: It looks like the subsequence limits only after the query, so it keeps timing out.

Comment: It is the recommended method (see second example of http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.search), and it takes an iterator, so it should evaluate all first. Get rid of the max-occurs, and run unfiltered, that might help..

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code to get this working.

```
var date = "2015-06-16T07:11:10.0Z";
var b    = cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("Dtm", ">", date);
var c    = fn.subsequence(cts.search(b, ['unfiltered']), 1, 10);
```

Thanks to @grtjn.

Comment: sure :) feel free to copy it

Comment: Copied. It makes your answer a bit redundant thogh, that is why I asked.. ;-)